# Using openpyxl in Python, how do I return the current row number?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to create Python code that reads data from a certain cell in an Excel file and returns a specified value based on a dictionary key.

I am using a for loop to iterate over each row, checking if the key exists within the cell.value located in column 'D' and want it to then assign the value to a column 'H' and row x where x is the current row.

```
logging.debug(wb.sheetnames)
ws = wb['Sheet1']
for cell in ws['D']:
    for k, v in dictKey.items():
        if k in cell.value:
            logging.debug(v)
            ws['H1'] = v
```

I have shown H1 as a static example of what I am trying to achieve but want it to be H2, H3, H4 for each row being interated.

I thought perhaps I could create a simple:

```
count = 0
count += 1
```

at the start of the for loop and then concatenate the value using:

`ws['H' + str(count)] = v`

But i thought there could be a more elegant solution using an inbuilt function in openpyxl?

I could not find a clean solution after a quick search and wondering if the above would work/be good code?

Thanks

Comment: `cell.row` I recommend you work your way through the openpyxl tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for `ws.cell(row, column).value` which let's you get and set based on index (index starting 1 cause it's openpyxl).

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html?highlight=cell.value